# I need help parsing strings in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I am trying to figure out how to extract just the name [Ethernet 1] of the LAN network associated with the **Intel(R)Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V** Network using windows batch script. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Name             : Ethernet 2
Description      : ASIX AX88178A USB 2.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
GUID             : 0ea309e6-b450-460e-946e-4f22abd4758b
Physical Address : 70-B3-D5-39-25-8B
State            : Network cable unplugged

Name             : Ethernet 3
Description      : ASIX AX88178A USB 2.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter #2
GUID             : 086fbb18-2cd4-4ce6-b286-74b2f66b3288
Physical Address : 70-B3-D5-39-25-8C
State            : Network cable unplugged

Name             : Ethernet 1
Description      : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
GUID             : b29c769f-ef3a-47c8-a709-474c11137df8
Physical Address : F4-4D-30-65-73-48
State            : Connected. Network does not support authentication.
```

Comment: @jeb not sure if duplicate! This needs to combine two lines (where Description eq Intel-foo) -> get line above and value of that! I would not see this as an exact duplicate!

Comment: Now we know what you are trying to do, but you should not forget to ask a specific question then, as StackOverflow is a *question* and answer portal. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! Which command do these data come from?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for`loop to parse the textfile (or command output), inside use a little trick to remember the previous line. If current line is your searchstring, then the remembered previous line is your wanted string.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "prev="

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('type t.txt^|findstr "Name Description"') do (
   REM here %%a is the current line and !prev! is the previous line
   if "%%a"==" Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V" set result=!prev:~1!
   set "prev=%%a"
)
echo Name: %result%
```

Note: there is a leading space with the second token. `~1` removes this.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: works fine for me (`t.txt` contains the data given in the question)

Comment: Nevermind... I am an idiot. I forgot the relevant data while copying. Nice trick!

Comment: Isn`t more efficient use in the subject of for loop following command:

    ('findstr "Name Description" t.txt')

Comment: @user2956477 maybe. But if you want to parse the output of a command, just replace `type t.txt` by your command (probably `netsh lan show interfaces` in this case: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh lan show interfaces^|findstr "Name Description"') do (
`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is easier to modify in order to fulfill other similar restrictions, like process more groups, test for more than one value in each group or with more lines between the search and desired values, etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('findstr "Name Description" input.txt') do (
   set "%%a=%%c"
   if "!Description!" equ "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V" echo !Name!
)
```